# Mongodb aggregation query by grouping multiple collections

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have two collections in mongodb.

### requests collection

1. _id
2. ipaddress
3. createdon

### geoip collection

1. _id
2. ipaddress
3. country
4. city

geoip is a look up table for IP address, which is unique here.

I need the following result, to find the total number of requests from each country. In other words, the following 2 columns.

country and recordcount (from requests collection based on the ipaddress)

Since this requires grouping 2 separate collections and combining them to get the results, I am at a loss here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to use a [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup) stage operation which is used to perform joins with other collections and fetch the results. Then group on the selected field to the required counts.

```
[
 {$lookup: {
    from: 'geoip',
    localField: 'ipaddress',
    foreignField: 'ipaddress',
    as: 'data'
 }},
 {$unwind: 'data'},
 {$group: {_id: '$data.country', count: {$sum: 1}}}

]
```

Comment: This works great!  Is it possible to achieve this through map reduce as lookup is not supported in older mongodb versions.

Comment: @FoxShrill I havn't used map-reduce a lot. You can probably read up on this here http://tebros.com/2011/07/using-mongodb-mapreduce-to-join-2-collections/

Comment: map/reduce did not support any form of cross-collection join; the best you could do would be to run two separate map/reduce steps and have the second one "reduce" the output of the first, filling in the missing data... but it would be really inefficient

Comment: but how to do it if we need to join 3 collections for ex?